# How to add servlet filters to Spring Boot Actuator management endpoints like health, metrics, jolokia?

Tags: spring-boot, servlet-filters, spring-boot-actuator, jolokia

How can I add servlet filters to Spring Boot Actuator management endpoints like health, metrics, jolokia etc.? Or do I have to use interceptors instead?

Background: I want to log requests that are sent to `<IP>:<managementPort>/jolokia`

Comment: I'm struggling with this too... Any help would be greatly appreciated